# how can i recovery my files from internal storage

Tags: root-access, internal-storage, data-recovery

I have samsung s20 fe g780g/ds, android 13. all my files in image gallery are lost or deleted. I would like to recovery but i cant access internal storage for recovery software. my phone is also not rooted. There are many topic like this but they are piece by piece, not fully explain. I have to  root my phone or is there any another way to recovery?

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Looks like this question is a duplicate of an existing question. Please have a look.

Comment: the linked answer applies for FDE encryption with ext4 file system only. your device is FBE encryption with f2fs file system = unrecoverable